# Python 3x. Panda print number of counted rows from csv for specific index_col

Tags: python-3.x, csv, printing, count, rows

I am trying to add into my code a print where it will be say how many rows was used for the specific index_col.

Please lets see an example below.

```
import pandas as pd
def a2c():
data = pd.read_csv("Claims.csv", sep=";", index_col="A2C")
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
while True:
    try:
        vstup=input("Zadejte A2C: ")
        print(data.loc[vstup])
    except KeyError:
        print("Špatná hodnota 1")
        break

def qn():
    data = pd.read_csv("Claims.csv", sep=";", index_col="QN")
    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
    while True:
        try:
           # print( data.dtypes)
            vstup=(input("Zadejte QN: "))
            print(data.loc[vstup])
        except KeyError:
            print("Špatná hodnota 1")
            break

while True:
    print("1)  QN \t\t = Číslo 13tkového hlášení\n2)  Druh \t = CO/CW/DD/II/PC\n3)  NR \t\t = Číslo NR hlášení\n4)  Zákazník \t = Název Zákazníka(Vše velkýmy písmeny)\n5)  Dodavatel\t = Celý název dodavatele\n6)  FF \t\t = BDY_FF1 / BDY_FF2 / BDY_FF3  -> Lze použít pro přehled nezpracovaných reklamací při volbě 0\n7)  A2C \t = Čislo A2C komponentu\n8)  Dod \t = Číslo dodavatele\n9)  UIDA \t = Číslo UIDY\n10) L \t\t = Číslo první Liability\n11) Cycle \t = Datum zastavení Cycle Time ")
    vstup=input("\nZadejte co hledáte: ")
    if vstup == "6":
        ff()
    elif vstup == "Zalozeno":
        print("Zadejte datum založení reklamace ve formě DD/MM/YY")
        zalozeno()
    elif vstup == "1":
        qn()
```

If I tried to add there :

```
vstup=input("Zadejte A2C: ")
print(data.loc[vstup])
print(len(data)
```

It counted all rows from the cvs file not for the index A2C for example.

What can I use to see the rows count for specific index?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to this

```
vstup=input("Zadejte A2C: ")
print(sum(df.index == vstup))
```

it will give you the count of rows corresponding to given index

Comment: that was not fully coorect??

Comment: Yes, it helped me to figure it out the problem.  (Sorry if it sound ironic, I didn´t mean it like that I just wanted to thank you for help.)